# Skype - remove from contacts or block user?

Tags: skype

I have temporary contacts in Skype that I want to remove when I no longer need them. So, if I just delete the user via `Remove from Contacts` option, will he be able to see me in his contacts after I delete him?

If this is true, then I guess option `Block User` (without checking `Report Abuse`) is the right way to completely remove both user from your contacts and yourself from his contacts.

I am asking this because I remember that MSN `delete user` option just deletes a user from your contact list while he still sees you in his.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com, and, since it's asking for the better of two working options, it's primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Scott: this question is too old to migrate.  My read of the question is there's a clear objective to ensure that removal affects the deleted contact and isn't just local.  The question seeks advice for an effective solution.  I wouldn't see that as being opinion based.  It isn't asking which way is better, just which way works or is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Removing the user will prevent them from continuing to see your status, but they will still be able to message you, or re-request authorization - they just will have no idea when you are online. In the vast majority of cases, this is the best option, and if your privacy preferences are set to only allow calls/messages from contacts, this will keep you from having to continue to deal with them - they may still see you in their list, but it won't do them any good.

Blocking them will prevent them from messaging you or requesting to add you to their contacts again. It should probably be reserved for serious issues, since it goes beyond removing them from contacts and it's a pain to unblock them if you ever need to contact them again.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie. As you said, I just want to remove them when we no longer cooperate, but I want to keep that they request re-authorization if such need comes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From main menu go to Contacts choose 'Advanced',choose 'Backup contacts to file'.

Make sure the Backup has extension .vcf.Do not block,just remove contacts,you are reluctant to deal with for an hour or few.Hold you Skype open for as long as you want.

You are seen only by wanted people.For unwanted you look like you didn't turn on the application at all. Upon finishing the session go the same route, but this time you'll need to 'Restore contacts from file'. You'll have all the previous contacts activated again. People will not take offense.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into your https://people.live.com/   account
2. Chose the unnamed or odd contact that you can-not delete
3. Hover and choose “add to Skype”
4. Choose allow
5. On the skype page choose unblock if needed
6. Give the contact a name like “xyz”
7. Go through your entire list of unnamed contacts this way
8. When all of the skype contacts have synced with people, go back to skype
9. Choose to delete the newly named contact
10. Wait for these to sync again with people, may need to refresh “people contacts page”
11. Those annoying farts should now be gone!!!
    This is a slow process, contacts need to sync between programs so be patient. Appears the unnamed contact is not able to be serviced without a name, once it is added back to Skype with a name, it can be deleted at will.

Tim J Kelly
DIGITIM llc
TJKelly@digitimllc.com

Comment: I don't think the question relates to unnamed contacts or how to delete them.  It appears to be about specific contacts and the question is whether those people can still see the OP because deletion might remove them only  on the OP's end.  BTW, adding contact information to your posts isn't appropriate and may produce a lot of spam for you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.